# getting no-unused-vars for any recursive function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, recursion, eslint

I've realized that any recursive function will hit `no-unused-vars` error which I don't understand why

Simple recursion as below

```js
const factorial = (x: number) => {
  if (x === 0) return 1;

  return x * factorial(x - 1);
};
```

[image]

Comment: If you change const to var does it still occur?

Comment: @TusharShahi: yes still getting it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the thing: if you declare a variable that is not exported (that means it cannot be used outside the file), you will have to use it in the file or export the function. So, you could do either this:

```
export const factorial = (x: number): number => {
  if (x === 0) return 1;

  return x * factorial(x - 1);
};
```

or call the function in the file:

```
const factorial = (x: number): number => {
  if (x === 0) return 1;

  return x * factorial(x - 1);
};

factorial(42);
```

See here: https://tsplay.dev/w11ekw

Comment: interesting, i was expecting the error to be thrown at the factorial beside `const` instead of the inner `factorial`. Personally will feel that the location of the error is a mistake but oh well...